# how to retrive specific data from serialized array in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want retrieve data of tiffin and show  in it tiffin div and lunch lunch div from a serialized array. But am getting in the following manner.folling are the images

**lunch**
[image: lunch]

**tiffin**
[image: tiffin]

and here is my code

checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?>" class="Foodmenu" value="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?>" name="tifeen[]" hidden>

<input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $lunch['lunch_name'];?>" class="Foodmenu" value="<?php  echo $lunch['lunch_name'];?>" name="lunch[]" hidden>
```

jQuery

```
$(".Foodmenu").click(function(){
    var checkedFood = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
        console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize());
        return $(this).attr('value');
    }).get().join("<br>");
    $("#selectedfood").html(checkedFood);
});
```

response divs

```
  <li role="presentation" class="active"  ><a href="#tiffin" id="selectedfood" aria-controls="home" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab" >Breakfast  </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#lunch" id="selectedfood" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> <i></i> Lunch </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#dinner" id="selectedfood" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Dinner </a></li>
```

How can i take only lunch data from that array to show it in response div

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Bind them in the different event

Comment: i have tried them binding different events but in vein